# Eliminating extra dot before section number

Tags: sectioning

I have created a document which uses the `book` class and in which the chapter headings consist of the number of the chapter, followed by a dot, a space and the title of the chapter; please see this example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{\@startsection
  {chapter}
  {0}
  {-\parindent}
  {\baselineskip}
  {\baselineskip}
  {\normalfont\Huge\textbf}}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{First}
Some random text.
\end{document}
```

The problem with the approach that I have used is that (as some of you may have already guessed even without compiling it) that that section heading appears as `1..1  First` rather than `1.1  First`. How do I do to keep the dot at the chapter heading, while at the same time removing it from the section heading?

Comment: Add `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}`

Comment: what should happen if you reference a chapter? Do you want the dot there or not?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that will not occur, but if it did then I would *not* want it to be there.

Comment: @SimonDispa You made me feel silly, but in a good way. Thank you.

Comment: well in this case you should not put the dot inside \thechapter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, of course. The problem is: I want to have that dot at the chapter heading.

Comment: Redefine `\@seccntformat`. The default definition is `\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}`. You can test if `#1` is chapter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you.